# C# shift schedule using timer when the date changes

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to write a C# form application that serves as a work shift schedule. The user can enter start time, break time and stop time and each contains hour and minute part. 
The program will be kept running for 24 hours a day non stop, and each time a set time arrives, a message needs to be displayed. So for example, if start time is 6:00, break time is 10:00 and stop time is 14:00, then every day at those times, the screen should keep displaying a message "start", "break", and "done" respectively. Of course, once the break is over, it says "start" again. When current time is not in the shift, it needs to keep saying "done". My program works fine if the shift starts and stops in the same day. However, if the shift includes date change (e.g. start-20:00, break-23:00, end-3:00 etc), it gets messed up when the current time becomes midnight.

I have check_during_shift method that checks if the current time is in the range of start and stop times, and check_shift_end_same_day method that checks if the shift starts and ends in the same day.

```
private TimeSpan start;
private TimeSpan breakBegin;
private TimeSpan breakEnd;
private TimeSpan stop;
private TimeSpan current;
//The timer runs every second
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
  //set each TimeSpan variables
  start = TimeSpan.Parse(startHour + ":" + startMinute);
  //same way for breakBegin, breakEnd, and stop (not written on here)
  current = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

  //if current time is NOT during the shift time
  if(check_during_shift(start, stop, current) == false){
      /* display "done" message */
  }
  //currently during the shift
  else{
     //this shift starts and ends in the same day
     if(check_shift_end_same_day(start, stop) == false){
       //add one day for the times that are on the next day 
       TimeSpan nextDay = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0); //1 day timeSpan
       if(start > breakBegin){
         //add one day to breakBegin, breakEnd, and stop
         breakBegin = breakBegin.Add(nextDay);
         breakEnd = breakEnd.Add(nextDay);
         stop = stop.Add(nextDay);
       }
       if(breakBegin > breakEnd){
         /*similarly, add one day to breakEnd and stop*/
       }
       if(breakEnd > stop){
         /*similarly, add one day to stop*/
       }
     }

     //check if current time fits somewhere in the time range
     if(current >= start && current < breakBegin){
        /*display "start" message*/
     }
     else if(current >= breakBegin && current < breakEnd){
        /*display "break" message*/
     }
     else if(current >= breakEnd && current < stop){
        /*display "start" message*/
     }
  }
}

private void check_during_shift(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan stop, TimeSpan current){
  if(start <= stop){
     if(current >= start && current <= stop) return true;
     else return false;
  }
  else{
     if(current >= start || current <= stop) return true;
     else return false;
  }
}

private void check_shift_end_same_day(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan stop){
   if(start <= stop) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

This program does not work when the shift ends on the next day. It only works for shifts that start and end within the same day. I noticed that at midnight, the program adds one day to times, even though the program added one day in the previous day already. 
Can anyone help me find how to fix this, please? Thank you.

Comment: You haven't given us any code that mutates a date, so it's hard to say.

Comment: mutates a date?

Comment: That last edit helps a bit.

Comment: let me know if you need more code. I am willing to show anything I have, if it can help